# Very difficult issue - "Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!"

Tags: spring, hibernate

We've been having a problem now for months that is killing us, and we have to bounce tomcat for - initially it happened every couple months, but with more and more users, it's happening now almost daily. Multiple people have looked at it, and so far haven't been able to figure out why we get this after the app has been up for several hours.  We're using the hibernate open session view pattern where we have a hibernate session opened for the request/response lifecycle.  Currently, after about several hours of load in production, we start getting this error and users start seeing issues and we have to bounce tomcat:

> "Could not open Hibernate Session for the transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!"

```
We're using hibernate 4.3.11.final, spring 4.3.7.RELEASE, and HikariCP version 3.1.0
```

Here are the parameters we're passing to the Hikari pool.

```
    <property name="minimumIdle" value="${database.pool.minIdle}" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="180000" />                              
    <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="180000" />
```

Unfortunately, this app is fairly old and uses a few different "techniques" to do data access - some of the code uses jdbctemplate, some uses hibernate with entities.

My latest thought is, maybe Hikari is closing a connection between the time hibernate opens it at the start of the request/response cycle and the end when it gets closed, but it's like finding a needle in a haystack.

Any help at all, even pointing in a direction, would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: is it possible that DB connections are more than maximumPoolSize and so Hickari can't open at all a new connection or closes an existing session?

Comment: How do you acquire session?

Comment: We're using the OpenSessionInViewFilter:

 <filter>
   <filter-name>configOpenSessionFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
    <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
    </init-param>      
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>configOpenSessionFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

Comment: ALso I'll add, when this happens, we always examine the memory and cpu, and they are usually really good, like memory is around 1/2 and cpu is very low.